# How to avoid multiple alter box when user clicks on back button of Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, restriction, backspace

I have written a code to disable to backbutton of Mozilla Firefox browser and show the pop-up alert,  but when I hit back button/ backspace multiple times, I am getting the alert box that number of times.
Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: You cannot disable the back button of FF. I wouldn't visit your website if you yet could...

Comment: Alright,  but somehow user should not be allowed to click backbutton. For example user is doing some payment and click on Mozilla browser backbutton, then user should get popup alert box.

Comment: Can anyone help me in this please?